# How do I start the main method to set a service type for vehicle

Tags: java, program-entry-point, mutators

I am trying to write main method for vehicle service type. Any help will be appreciated please, I have aready created a setter for my serviceType variable.

```
public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
  this.serviceType = serviceType;
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: That is only the setter for a member of some class. Please show us more code, especially the class this is a part of.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Object o=new Object();
    o.setServiceType("Full Service");
}
```

At least I assume this is what you meant to ask? I would recommend taking a step back and doing some reading on the basics of the Java language, as the Hello World example would teach you enough to not need to ask this.